# Python serial write loop

Tags: python

I need to control the power in Python and loop it.

My problem is that I don't want to type `ser.write(b'APPL 8,1.6\n')` again.

How can I code it?

```
import serial
from serial import Serial
from time import sleep
COM_PORT = 'COM5'  
BAUD_RATES = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(COM_PORT, BAUD_RATES)
ser.write(b'APPL 8,1.6\n')
ser.write(b':CHAN1:VOLT?;CURR?\n')
print (ser.readline())
print ("---wait  10seconds !!------")
time.sleep(10)
ser.write(b'APPL 9,1.7\n')
ser.write(b':CHAN1:VOLT?;CURR?\n')
print (ser.readline())
print ("---wait  10seconds !!------")
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: And how do you want to set the power at each loop statement ? How do you want to contorl it ? That's unclear please **edit** your post with details

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear. But it seems you just want to perpetually loop the query. You can just assign your bytes to a variable or global variable and just use that.

```
import serial
from serial import Serial
from time import sleep
COM_PORT = 'COM5'  
BAUD_RATES = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(COM_PORT, BAUD_RATES)
a_816 = b'APPL 8,1.6\n'
a_917 = b'APPL 9,1.7\n'
cc = b':CHAN1:VOLT?;CURR?\n'
while(1):

    ser.write(a_816)
    ser.write(cc)
    print (ser.readline())
    print ("---wait  10seconds !!------")
    time.sleep(10)
    ser.write(a_917)
    ser.write(cc)
    print (ser.readline())
    print ("---wait  10seconds !!------")
    time.sleep(10)
```

You might want to look into multi-threading if you want to do more with the python program than just printing the status.

EDIT: Extended

```
import serial
from serial import Serial
from time import sleep
COM_PORT = 'COM5'  
BAUD_RATES = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(COM_PORT, BAUD_RATES)
str1_static = "APPL "
str2_static = ",100\n"
cc = b':CHAN1:VOLT?;CURR?\n'
k = 16 #your starting value
while k>= 0:
    str_dynamic = str(k)
    b = bytes(str1_static + str_dynamic + str2_static,'utf-8')
    ser.write(b)
    ser.write(cc)
    k-=0.5
    print (b)
    print ("---wait  10seconds !!------")
    time.sleep(10)
```

This ought to work.

Comment: If I need to a_816 = b'APPL 8,1.6\n'  loop the count to 0 --> average -0.5 (8,7.5,7....) how can I code it ?  thank you !!

Comment: You're getting more confusing now, what do you mean loop the count to 0? There is no counter in your code snippet. And what is average -0.5(8.7,5.7) supposed to be? Please explain a little bit more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
COM_PORT = 'COM5'  
BAUD_RATES = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(COM_PORT, BAUD_RATES)
a1= b'APPL 16,100\n'
a2 = b'APPL 15.5,100\n'
a3= b'APPL 15,100\n'
a4= b'APPL 14.5,100\n'  

If I don't want to type the global variable so much.. how can I code it ?  
count to 0 mean is
 b'APPL 15.5,100 \n ->b'APPL 15,100\n ....->b'APPL 0,100\n .. Thank you!
```

I want  global variable can loop .
   b'APPL 15,100\n'-> the command is to set the voltage,current -> I need to 
   repeat it,so I want to find the method to reduce repeat times.